# javascript calling a php file in src , the proper way

Tags: php, javascript, src, document.write

I am including the following javascript code in my HTML  , which in turn makes a reference to a php file for doing a backend job :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--//<![CDATA[
var partnerId = "100b70a8a2248717";
var siteId = "12418";
var m3_u =    (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://javascriptGetAd.php':'http://javascriptGetAd.php');
var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
document.write ("?partner_id=" + partnerId);
document.write ('&amp;site_id=' + siteId);
document.write ('&amp;version=1.5');
document.write ('&amp;language=javascript');
document.write ('&amp;format=wap');
document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
//]]>-->
```

Can I call javascriptGetAd.php from inside a javascript function in any other way without using document.write() as shown above ?

Comment: What does your php return? Javascript?

Comment: @biziclop ...yes...my php returns some data in javascript format

Comment: Maybe this way: http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html

Comment: You could probably make this an ajax call, but I don't see any value add for doing what your asking. This format is common for ad code and tracking software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX for this purpose

```
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");




  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
         // Handle xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","javascriptGetAd.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```